# How to know which element is clicked from ElementsByClassName (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("small_key");

for(i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].addEventListener("click", keyClick);
}
```

I have the code above and want to know how to write the function "keyClick" so that I know which one of all the elements that's clicked.

```
function keyClick(){}
```

This question is not duiplicated since the other question is for document.getElementById and this for document.getElementsByClass. With the difference, getElementById return one element while getElementsByClass returns one or more. I didn't know if it was the same way when you put more than one element with the same listener...

Comment: Side note: Your code is falling prey to [The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Be sure to declare your variables (such as `i` above).

Comment: (I'm newbie to javascript) What do you mean? Like this, for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++)

Comment: Yes. Or (with modern JavaScript) you might use `let`, depending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within `keyClick`, `this` will refer to the element on which you hooked the event. (It's also available as `currentTarget` on the event object `keyClick` receives.) If you want to know what element was actually clicked (e.g, if it was a descendant element of the `.small_key` element on which you hooked up the handler), that's `target` on the event object. If the click was directly on the `.small_key` element (not a descendant), `currentTarget` and `target` will be the same.

Example:

```js
var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("small_key");

for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].addEventListener("click", keyClick);
}

function keyClick(e) {
  console.log("this.id = " + this.id);
  console.log("e.currentTarget.id = " + e.currentTarget.id);
  console.log("e.target.id = " + e.target.id);
}
```

```html
<p> Try clicking directly on "bbbb", and also on (span within bbbb)</p>
<div id="a" class="small_key">aaaa</div>
<div id="b" class="small_key">bbbb <span id="b-span">(span within bbbb)</span></div>
<div id="c" class="small_key">cccc</div>
<div id="d" class="small_key">dddd</div>
<div id="e" class="small_key">eeee</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L5njx82g/1/)

You can use `this` to refer the current object who is raising the event.

```
var keys = document.getElementsByClassName("small_key");

for(i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    keys[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ var ctrl = this; keyClick(this); });
}

function keyClick(obj){
    console.log(obj);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Why down votes ? It is returning the required DOM element on click event.  Add appropriate comments if downvoting.